# Moving through datarepeater's items

Tags: vb.net, datarepeater

Is there any way to move through datarepeater's items through code, as we run loop and move through the items in a list / combo box?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataRepeater1.ItemCount -1
       Me.DataRepeater1.CurrentItemIndex = i
       Dim item As DataRepeaterItem = Me.DataRepeater1.CurrentItem
   Next
```

Answer (score 5):

The code from Schmelter changes the current row, but this might produce undesired effects since it can update the UI and causes other data-handling events to fire.  It's not necessary to change the CurrentItemIndex to loop through the DataRepeaterItems.  Each DataRepeaterItem is just a Control object in the DataRepeater.Controls collection.  Here is an alternative (in C#):

```
    using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks; 
    foreach ( DataRepeaterItem rowItem in dataRepeater1.Controls )
    {
        int itemIndex = rowItem.ItemIndex;

        // If it's bound, get the underlying data object
        object dataItem = BindingSource1.List[itemIndex];

        // Add code for each rowItem of the dataItem
        // All controls on the DataRepeateItem can be obtained from rowItem.Controls  
    }
```